# Static IP Connection to the internet fails once in a while (too much)

Tags: networking, dhcp, wireshark

I live in a dorm that the whole building shares a /24 subnet. IP assignments are static (static IP, static DNS, and static Gateway). Since one month, my internet connection on the windows fails once in a while. (As much as 10 times per day on some days) And I just restart the Ethernet Adapter (disable, enable) to fix it temporarily.

I had a WIFI router with static WAN, (with the same configuration). But since one month, connecting it only means that It loses internet connection and WIFI coverage only after a couple of minutes for sure.

The dorm administrators told me to check if a neighbor in the Subnet has set their settings for Dynamic IP allocation, and suggested that that could confuse my Laptop in contacting them instead of The real servers.

Is that even possible to mess with a statically configured node in your Subnet?
And how do I check if this is really the case, with Wireshark? (I also have ubuntu if suits better)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I thinks some like an Ip conflict is going on. So that means someone is using your ip. If you look into the router you can see the device name which is using your ip address.

Comment: @SkyRamon I don't get it. The router is only in my room. So it is configured like my laptop Ethernet adapter, to connect to the outside world, which is the /24 sub-net. You did get that right?

Comment: Is your laptop trying to use the same IP as your router?  

Is your router trying to use the same subnet as the 'external' network?  

Is your router using the same IP as another device on the 'external' network?  

When you lose connection, what other hosts are affected?  

Is your laptop running off your router or the 'external' network?  

Which device(s) is(are) losing connection?

Comment: @Xalorous So there is one female Ethernet port in my wall, that brings the /24 subnet in my room. I EITHER connect it with a cable to my router, and have WIFI in the room, OR disable the router completely and stick the cable into my laptop. So there is no 'confilict' between them. Since there are too many rooms, I can't check everybody's IP configuration in person, or ask the whole building if they are affected. I'm hoping to find that 'suspect' by looking at communications.

Comment: By the way each room has a dedicated IP.